# Azure CosmosDB get pagination data by a specific page number

Tags: python, pagination, azure-cosmosdb, fastapi

Background: FastAPI + CosmosDB

The [official pagination code example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos/test/test_query.py#L533) for the CosmosDB python SDK is show below. It only shown how to get the next page via page iterator. How can I get the pagination data by a specific page number?

> ```
>  def test_paging_with_continuation_token(self):
>     created_collection = self.config.create_multi_partition_collection_with_custom_pk_if_not_exist(self.client)
>
>     document_definition = {'pk': 'pk', 'id': '1'}
>     created_collection.create_item(body=document_definition)
>     document_definition = {'pk': 'pk', 'id': '2'}
>     created_collection.create_item(body=document_definition)
>
>     query = 'SELECT * from c'
>     query_iterable = created_collection.query_items(
>         query=query,
>         partition_key='pk',
>         max_item_count=1
>     )
>     pager = query_iterable.by_page()
>     pager.next()
>     token = pager.continuation_token
>     second_page = list(pager.next())[0]
>
>     pager = query_iterable.by_page(token)
>     second_page_fetched_with_continuation_token = list(pager.next())[0]
>
>     self.assertEqual(second_page['id'], second_page_fetched_with_continuation_token['id'])
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For pagination by specific page number, you can make use of [`OFFSET LIMIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-offset-limit) clause available in Cosmos DB SQL API.

All you need to do is specify the `offset` and `limit` clause in your query itself. Something like:

```
query = 'SELECT * from c OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1'
```

However, please note that using `OFFSET/LIMIT` increases RU consumption considerably. From the same link:

> **The RU charge of a query with OFFSET LIMIT will increase as the number
> of terms being offset increases**. For queries that have multiple pages
> of results, we typically recommend using continuation tokens.
> Continuation tokens are a "bookmark" for the place where the query can
> later resume. If you use OFFSET LIMIT, there is no "bookmark". If you
> wanted to return the query's next page, you would have to start from
> the beginning.

Comment: Seems continuation token is only suitable for next, previous style pagination.

Comment: One more question regarding using the continuation token, where do you recommend to store the token? In the cookies or the headers or neither?

Comment: Generally speaking, it is not recommended to store continuation tokens especially in permanent storage. For storing them temporarily, you can probably use in-page variables so that they’re gone once a user moves away from the page. Since tokens are specific to a query, you would need to clear them up in case user specifies another query to fetch the data.